# Dagger 2 binding the same fragment twice?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2

Hi I have a Module that binds two Frgaments of the same class, but each one has a parameter that gets passes to it to represent two different states of the same fragment.

Below is my module that binds another sub module containing my dependencies into the fragments:

```
@Module
abstract class ProductAndroidBinding{
    /**
     * Activity bindings here
     */


    /**
     * Fragment Bindings here
     */

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductModule ::class])
    @ViewScope
    abstract fun bindProductHomeFragment() : OffersHomeFragment

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductModule ::class])
    @ViewScope
    @Named("OldProducts")
    abstract fun binOldListFragment() : ProductsListFragment

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductModule ::class])
    @ViewScope
    @Named("NewReleasedProducts")
    abstract fun binNewProductsListFragment() : ProductsListFragment


}
```

I get the error below:

```
Error:(22, 2) error: @ContributesAndroidInjector methods cannot have qualifiers
    @javax.inject.Named(value = "NewReleasedProducts")
    ^
```

I thought using a named annotation allows you to bind multiple variants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ContributesAndroidInjector` is a convenience to generate a subcomponent that will take care of injecting your fragment, but it will not directly be added to the object graph. As such there is no qualifier that you could add to it (as of now).

> but each one has a parameter that gets passes to it to represent two different states of the same fragment

I would advise you to simply bind this parameter to Dagger. Provide it from a module, then do what you need with it.

```
@Module
abstract class ProductAndroidBinding{

  /**
   * Fragment Bindings here
   */

  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductModule::class])
  @ViewScope
  abstract fun binOldListFragment() : ProductsListFragment

}
```

...and provide / use it...

```
@Module class ProductModule {

  @Named("my_arg")
  @Provides provideParameter(fragment: ProductListFragment) : String {
    return fragment.arguments.getString("my_arg")
  }

  // then use it, e.g.
  @Provides providePresenter(@Named("my_arg") arg: String) : MyPresenter {
    return if(arg == "old") OldPresenter() else NewPresenter()
  }  

}
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick and made a lot of sense. Still learning dagger